# How to extract tar files from amazonS3 bucket to another s3 in Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, byte, inputstream

I have tar files in a S3 bucket and I'm trying to untar them in another s3 bucket.
So far I got all the files in the destBucket but it seems that the putObject makes the files corrupted or nulls. How to read the whole file and write the whole buffered in the putObject ?

Here the code I am using:

```
TarArchiveInputStream tarInputStream = new TarArchiveInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(objectData));

        TarArchiveEntry currentEntry;

        while ((currentEntry = tarInputStream.getNextTarEntry()) != null) {
            if (!currentEntry.isDirectory()) {
                byte[] objectBytes = new byte[currentEntry.getSize()];
                tarInputStream.read(objectBytes);
                def entryName = currentEntry.getName()
                def fileN = entryName.substring(entryName.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, entryName.length())

                ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
                metadata.setContentLength(objectBytes.length);
                metadata.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
                s3Client.putObject(destbucket, packagePath + "untar_frames/" + fileN,
                        new ByteArrayInputStream(objectBytes), metadata);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using V2 version of the Amazon S3 Java API. I have not seen an issue using PutObject when you properly set the byte[] with valid data. Also, make sure that you properly setup the **PutObjectRequest** object. See this code example.

https://github.com/scmacdon/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/javav2/example_code/s3/src/main/java/com/example/s3/PutObject.java

If you are not familiar with AWS SDK for Java V2, please refer to this [Quick Start](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html).